# sha256 string starting with custom like aaaaaa

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to generate a SHA256 string but I want it first 15 characters are same like `aaaaaaaa....`

and how can I do that?

```
FOUND: 9481011 aaaaaa4da30538b171d69304aba8a3a3d8bf4b83761c1fa30b8e40dd2f97b899
```

I need the exact string encrypted and decrypted so I need two strings

I need it created so when checked by other side it must be validated

```
don't down vote if you cant able to solve this
```

Comment: The point of a hash is that you can't do that.

Comment: but how the 'h' character encrypts like aaa...... ? I need first all 15 characters aaaaa... which combination does that

Comment: Well, the probability for a randomly selected string to be digested to a string starting with "aaa" is (1/16)^3, about 0.02 %. The probability of being digested to a string starting with 15 a's is only (1/16)^15, so about 8*10^-17 %

Comment: hmm nice... so programmaticly impossible right?

Comment: my system generates sha256 from one string so I need it to be generated as aaaaaa,,,,etc

Comment: I think you cant get the issue clearly

Comment: I suggest you to go learn about cryptographic hashes and how does it work.  What you are asking here is simply not possible with the hashes.

Comment: so why its possible to get three aaa's from 'h' character, it also must be impossible

Comment: @user8127445: You need to learn the basics of crypto.  The point of a hash is to prevent you from figuring out which inputs give a specific output.

Comment: (the point of a hash is not that some random specific output is impossible; every possible output is the hash of an infinite number of inputs).

Comment: @user8127445 Well, I already told you, the probability between those two cases differs by more than 14 orders of magnitude

Comment: @simmac how can I run this probability in node

Comment: @user8127445: You can write a `for` loop over every possible input.  You'll need to wait hundreds of thousands of years to get a result.

Comment: Things similar to this are done for custom BitCoin IDs but not 15 characters. Basically you keep trying different values until you get a hash you like. But with 16 characters that is going to be computationally infeasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is try lots of inputs until you find one that works:

```py
x = 0
while True:
    x += 1
    if sha256(str(x)).startswith('a' * 15):
        return str(x)
```

Unfortunately, you want so many `a` in a row that it will take decades for this method to finish. Every extra `a` increases the runtime by a factor 16.

If there was a simple way to find strings starting with lots of `a`, the hash function would not be secure. So this is the best you will be able to do, short of performing groundbreaking research in cryptography.

Comment: I found 5 a's in a minute

Comment: @user8127445 Be sure to report back in a year or two when you get to 10.

Comment: FOUND: 9481011 aaaaaa4da30538b171d69304aba8a3a3d8bf4b83761c1fa30b8e40dd2f97b899

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the SHA256 string is as follows:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
function sha256(data) {
    return crypto.createHash("sha256").update(data).digest("base64");
}
```

To get the first 15 characters to be repeated `a`s, you can either overwrite the first 15 characters or append 15 `a`s, as follows:

Overwrite:

```
var str = sha256("hello");
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    str = str.substr(0,index) + 'a' + str.substr(index+1);
}
```

Append:

```
var a = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
var str = a + sha256("hello");
```

Comment: no I need it created so when checked by other side it must be validated

Comment: @user8127445 I am not sure what you mean, "by the other side"

Comment: server checks the string if its generated from a string in sha256............ and I need it to start with aaaaaaaaa

Comment: With the appending method, you can have the string start with aaaaaa... and then remove it to check if it is valid SHA256 on the server side.

Comment: :) server doe that

Answer (score 0):

A sha256 hash is as its name implies, 256 bits long. That means there are $2^256$ different possibilities. That's about a trillion, trillion, trillion, trillion, trillion, trillion possibilities. (This is not a typo. That is trillion 6 times) Now, you want to find a string whose sha256 hash has a 15-character prefix. The best way we know how to do this is to guess random strings and check if they match your criteria. For every string that matches your criteria, there are roughly one trillion, trillion, trillion that do not. That is more than the number of stars in the observable universe.

Imagine laying next to a friend looking up at the night sky. Your friend picks a star and you have to guess which one they picked. You would not expect to win that game. Answering your question is more than a thousand times harder than winning at that game.